# Dlookup Returning the first field from the list regardless of the criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, dlookup

I am Working with a form  with a combo box (LaborType) and a text box (LaborCost1) I have the following code on the after update event of the combo box and it returns the same value no matter the criteria.

```
[LaborCost1] = DLookup("LaborCost", "LaborTypesAndCost", LaborType = Me.LaborType)
```

Comment: That will only happen if LaborCost is the same for all LaborTypes.

Comment: There are currently two records in that table and they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

If `LaborType` is numeric:

```
DLookup("LaborCost", "LaborTypesAndCost", "LaborType = " & Me.LaborType)
```

If `LaborType` is text:

```
DLookup("LaborCost", "LaborTypesAndCost", "LaborType = '" & Me.LaborType & "'")
```

Comment: Labor Type is Text and I tried the Code sent and it is still returning the same result no matter the criteria.

Comment: Are you sure the AfterUpdate() event is firing?

Comment: I have also run the same code on the  OnChange event and I am getting the same result. So I believe that the event is firing.

Comment: Well, the control should have the word `[Event Procedure]` on the relevant event in the properties/events tab - have you checked it?

Comment: Is the combo multi-column? If yes, which column is bounded?

Comment: Yes it is on both after update and on Change

Comment: Yes it is multi column and the first column is bound

Comment: So the first column should be the text for LaborType. if it's not, then give the column number where the text is located, e.g. `Me.LaborType.Column(1)` (for the second column).

Comment: The first column is the labor type and it is formatted as text in both tables

Comment: I'm not talking about the table but the combobox control.

Comment: Yes the first column in the combo box Control is text.

Comment: I found a spelling error in one of the tables and the code you sent is now working thank you for the help.